# How to Programmatically communicate with Restful API using SSH tunnelling

Tags: api, asp.net-core, openstack, ssh-tunnel

I am building a Restful API client using .NET core framework. The APIs are OpenStack API, however, because of the network configuration, I cannot access the API from my local computer (also development computer), I have to ssh into a machine that can ssh into the OpenStack infrastructure when accessing OpenStack normally.

Bearing this in mind, is it possible to use SSH tunnel for the API endpoints and then call it in the implemented Web API client? I have tried to do this, but the call to the endpoint returns error 401 - content length is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically its possible to call the Openstack API endpoint through an SSH-tunnel without any public accessible API-endpoints. Bacause I have no experience with .NET core framework this answer is really generic without C# code. I hope it helps you anyway.

IMPORTANT: You can use the following steps only, when you have a admin-login to the openstack-deployment and you should ONLY!!! use this way, when the openstack-deployment is a test-deployment, where breaking the deployment doesn't affect other users.

#### 1. SSH-tunnel

You can forward ports with the command:

`ssh -L 127.0.0.1:<PORT>:<IP_REMOTE>:<PORT> <USER_JUMPHOST>@<IP_JUMPHOST> -fN`

- `<PORT>` = Port of the Openstack-Component you want to access remotely (for example 5000 for keystone)
- `<IP_REMOTE>` = IP of the host, where your openstack deployment is running
- `<USER_JUMPHOST>@<IP_JUMPHOST>` = ssh-access to the jumphost, which is between you and your openstack deployment

This has to be done for each openstack component. If you don't want this command in the backgroup remove the `-fN` at the end.

Here at first you have to forward Keystone with port `5000`.

example: `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:5000:192.168.62.1:5000 deployer@192.168.67.1 -fN`

You can test the access via curl or webbrowser from your local pc:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
{"versions": {"values": [{"id": "v3.13", "status": "stable", "updated": "2019-07-19T00:00:00Z", "links": [{"rel": "self", "href": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/v3/"}], "media-types": [{"base": "application/json", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.identity-v3+json"}]}]}}
```

#### 2. change openstack-endpoints

To be also able to login on the openstack deployment through the tunnel, you have to change the endpoints to listen to the localhost on the remote system too, where your openstack depoyment is:

0. Login normally on your openstack deployment as admin-user.
1. List all endpoints: `openstack endpoint list`
2. Change the `public` and `internal`-endpoint of `keystone` to localhost:

`openstack endpoint set --url http://127.0.0.1:5000 <ID_OF_INTERNAL_KEYSTONE_ENDPOINT>`

After changing the internal endpoint it will break the openstack-login on the remotesystem for now, but don't worry.

3. Now you can login to the openstack via openstack-client from your local pc. Here you have to authorize against local-host. If you use an rc-file to login, you have to change the auth-url to `export OS_AUTH_URL=http://127.0.0.1:5000/v3`
4. Change the nova endpoints by running on your local pc `openstack endpoint set --url "http://127.0.0.1:8774/v2.1" <ID>` for the `internal` and `public` endpoint of nova to run commands like `openstack server list` through your ssh-tunnel (of course you need also an ssh-tunnel for port 8774) to do this.

#### 3. Authorize against the openstack-deployment

When you send HTTP-Requests without the openstack-client, you have to manually request an authentication token from the deployment:

0. Login normally on your openstack deployment
1. Make a Token-Request:

`curl -v -s -X POST "$OS_AUTH_URL/auth/tokens?nocatalog" -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d '{ "auth": { "identity": { "methods": ["password"],"password": {"user": {"domain": {"name": "'"$OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME"'"},"name": "'"$OS_USERNAME"'", "password": "'"$OS_PASSWORD"'"} } }, "scope": { "project": { "domain": { "name": "'"$OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME"'" }, "name":  "'"$OS_PROJECT_NAME"'" } } }}' --stderr - | grep X-Subject-Token`

This command can be used without changes. The Value after the Key X-Subject-Token is the token from Keystone. Copy this value and export the token as the environment variable `OS_TOKEN`. For example like the following line

```
export OS_TOKEN=gAAAAABZuj0GZ6g05tKJ0hvihAKXNJgzfoT4TSCgR7cgWaKvIvbD66StJK6cS3FqzR2DosmqofnR_N-HztJXUcVhwF04HQsY9CBqQC7pblGnNIDWCXxnJiCH_jc4W-uMPNA6FBK9TT27vE5q5AIa487GcLLkeJxdchXiDJvw6wHty680eJx3kL4
```

2. Make requests with the token.

For example GET-Requests with curl:

`curl -s -X GET -H "X-Auth-Token: $OS_TOKEN" http://127.0.0.1:5000/v3/users | python -m json.tool`

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I previously did exactly what you explained in section 1 of your answer, however, I did it using Putty because I use a windows 7 system. The issue now is, I do not have admin privilege to OpenStack, and others use it, so I won't be able to change the endpoints. Is there a workaround for this?

I believe the reason my call to the API endpoint is not working is because I have not implemented what you described in part 2.

Comment: hmmm, yeah, there would also another solution. You could use port-forwarding on your local pc. In linux it also works with `sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --dst <IP_OF_REMOTE> -p tcp --dport <PORT> -j REDIRECT --to-ports <PORT>` (sorry, I don't know, how this can be done in windows). It worked well with the openstack-client in my test here. The `<IP_OF_REMOTE>` have to match the ip-address of the openstack-deployment. That way you force all requests against the depoyment into the ssh-tunnel.

Comment: Arrr, stupid mistake from my side. This redirecting/endpoint stuff of section 2 is only necessary, when you use the openstack-client, because it get the addresses for requests over the endpoint-list of the openstack-deployment. When you call the API with your own HTTP-requests like in the steps of section 3, it works even without the changes of section 2. sorry :(

Comment: Thank you. I was just about to message you and say I got it working just now. I didn't need to do step 2. I wonder why it didn't work previously though, because I didn't change my setup, I only changed some bit of the code.

Thanks once again.